# Photoshop: How to make batch automation save multiple images?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, batch-processing

I have an action in Photoshop that applies some filters and saves the image, then applies some more filters and saves it again, and so on.

But when I try to use this action in a batch automation and override the 'save as' command photoshop just saves the same image over and over again.

P.S: I have tried to change the name in all of the save action but the issue stands.

[image: The First part of my action]

Comment: overriding save as will result in only the last one being the final file.  youre replacing save as for ctrl s

Answer (score 1):

My *homemade* solution:

- Create a folder where to put the images
- Inside this folder, create as many folders as different saves commands the action will have, example folder01, folder02, folder03, etc.
- Change the Save Action command destination to those folders, one for each.

[image: Action]

- Batch:

[image: batch window]

- The result is each image with its action in each folder

[image: flowers]

Answer (score -3):

Please download this file [Save and Close](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4fcX5Te1_PKMkNKWkMwOE5LcG8/view?usp=sharing)

1. Then open your folder via `file->automate`
2. Run the downloaded action
3. Never override

> U can customise the action by putting your actions before the downloaded one

Comment: It would be better if you explain how to create the batch actions instead.  We expect complete answers not just a link to a file in your drive and asking people to download it.