# Automation for Batch-Converting Images for Ecomm - must have square canvas - Ug

Tags: photoshop-scripting, automation, batch-processing, image-editing, image-format

First time here and hope this is a good place to ask.

Looking for a quick way/automation to convert multiple print quality images (30-70MB) to 1000x1000 pixels at 300 dpi and under 3 MB for use in web applications.

WHAT I WANT TO HAPPEN
Open the file (that already has image and is named with correct UPC) hit the magical automate function that automatically puts the image in those constraints first mentioned...  Has anyone created a script or an action or have any other idea?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What have you tried? Did you see [this question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/79124/photoshop-how-to-make-batch-automation-save-multiple-images)?

Comment: I use actions so not really about how to use actions.. The rub is the Canvas size. Sometimes images are horizontal and sometimes vertical. So I can make an automation to make the longest side 1000 pix at 300 dpi. but not either-or. Once that is done I can automate the canvas to 1000. What I can't do - is take a large image and make it small AND make the canvas 1000 on both sides automatically ..

Comment: I have a Action made to bring down the large images I think. And one for Changing Longest sides. So two diff actions depending on image type. Guess that's as good as I can hope for. I was hoping for a script or applet or something that would read the image and change it to what I needed - no matter what it was in the beginning.. may have been asking for too much. Thanks anyways!!

Comment: Do you care how the images are cropped to a 1:1 ratio? If you do it as an action then your crop will be center center.

Comment: Yes, it matters.. it's grocery products for ecomm so they need the whole image. I can get it to do what I want depending on the original file - but can't make a one-action fixes all action. Basically I can't drop any random image into the action and have it spit it out perfect. That's what I really want

Comment: @JoshuaFarnum that might not be possible.  Unless the subject is in the exact same place in every photo, then the same action applied to every image is not going to work. The problem is that Photoshop knows nothing about what is in an image. If you have a lot of images to crop to 1:1 it might be better to have a look at Adobe Lightroom. The benefit of Lightroom is that you can quickly apply manual crops, without the need to save after each crop. When all is done you could then export all the images in one go, at the required size and resolution.

Comment: As other mentioned! Can you explain if you wanna crop your image to 1000px or you want to resize it proportionally to 1000px(with remaining black pixel containing white/black) if that's the case then you can use either action/script to automate this stuff. provide little more detail with some pics if possible so we can help easily